# javascript confirmation message not resetting

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm working with an application which is a bit old and uses some oldschool methods.

The thing is:

We have a pop-up with multiple textboxes, comboboxes basicly input components as shown below

[image]

Everytime a user changes any field or navigates trough them the page is refreshed for validation. Everytime a validation fails we add a message to a confirmation box like this ( one of the validations exemple ):

```
string jscript = string.Empty;
if ( situacao != benOld.Situacao.Codigo && 
                             situacao != (int) SituacaoBeneficiarioEnum.Suspenso &&
                             benOld.Situacao.Codigo != (int)SituacaoBeneficiarioEnum.Suspenso &&
                             datasituacao < benOld.DataSituacao &&
                             datasituacao != Constants.NULLDATE)
jscript = jscript + " var i; for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) { ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i]); } ValidatorUpdateIsValid();  if ( Page_IsValid ){ "+ Pergunta5()+" } ";
```

and after all the validations we have:

```
Toolbar.ActionSave.ClientAction = jscript +" var i; for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) { ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i]); } ValidatorUpdateIsValid();  if ( Page_IsValid ){ "+ jsNomesDep+" }";
```

ClientAction method:

```
public string ClientAction
    {
        get
        {
            return this.clientAction;
        }
        set
        {
            this.clientAction = value;

            if (this.ImageControl != null) this.ImageControl.Attributes.Add("onclick", value);
            //if (this.LinkControl != null) this.LinkControl.Attributes.Add("onclick", value);
        }
    }
```

When we submit the form a confirmation message pops out warning like:

"some validations went wrong, still wanna continue?"

and if the user presses OK the fields are submited and everything is OK.

The thing is: If the user really wants to change that field again he must press cancel, change the field and submit again. Our problem is that even if that validations go well in the second time the same confirmation message pops out again. As I can see the PostBack is not clearing the info of the message sent as javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your 'onclick' it's running only the 'get value'  so you aren't running the first part of your code, so this only runs once:

```
jscript = string.Empty;
if ( situacao != benOld.Situacao.Codigo && 
                             situacao != (int) SituacaoBeneficiarioEnum.Suspenso &&
                             benOld.Situacao.Codigo != (int)SituacaoBeneficiarioEnum.Suspenso &&
                             datasituacao < benOld.DataSituacao &&
                             datasituacao != Constants.NULLDATE)
jscript = jscript + " var i; for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) { ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i]); } ValidatorUpdateIsValid();  if ( Page_IsValid ){ "+ Pergunta5()+" } ";
```

Your message error will always be the same, that's what i think it's happening

Comment: Hey Mister Angelo Cocharra thanks for your reply,

everytime we click a component in this screen we do a Postback which calls a function we have that is the OnPreRender that calls that function of validation that puts the jscript variable empty

there is no problem with that variable on the server side we are able to clean them.

but when the user presses the button we send trough javascript in client side a confirmation message that we cant clean its content after the user presses Cancel and that is the message we want to clear ( client side )